# Publish Azure API App without using Visual Studio

Tags: azure-api-apps

I have created an Azure API App using visual studio. I run it locally its working fine then i published it to Azure from the Visual Studio publish -> Microsoft Azure API App option. The API app is deployed to Azure and working fine.

Is there any other option to deploy it to azure using publish package without using visual studio? If yes then how it can be done, please help.

Or can we create a package for the API App then can be used further?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to Publish using Visual Studio.  Underlying an API app is a "Host".  You can see this by browsing to the API app in Ibiza.  All the deployment options for Web Apps work with this host.  This article highlights the options: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/.